# undefined reference to `SSL_library_init' error during the compiling for C++ API

Tags: c++, dolphindb

undefined reference to `SSL_library_init' error during the compiling for C++ API

The OpenSSL version I used is 1.1.1, and the error is:

```
../bin/linux_x64/ABI0/libDolphinDBAPI.so: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
../bin/linux_x64/ABI0/libDolphinDBAPI.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
../bin/linux_x64/ABI0/libDolphinDBAPI.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you provide the command to build libDolphinDBAPI.so ??

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of OpenSSL? There may be problems with OpenSSL 1.1 and above, and OpenSSL 1.0 is required .
This is an example of compiling and installing OpenSSL from source code :

https://github.com/dolphindb/api-cplusplus

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."